# No puedo obtener el texto con javascript y vue.js, me lo envia null

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Estoy tratando de obtener el texto de la etiqueta `span` con javascript, pero el envío de los datos queda en null. Es de esta forma como tengo el código:

html:

```
  <div class="col-lg-10 ">
    <span id="trunc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
  </div>
```

javascript:

```
var lengthText = 90;
//Aqui en la variable text guardas el texto antes de ocultarlo
var text = $("#trunc").text();
var shortText = $.trim(text).substring(0, lengthText).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";
console.log(text);
console.log(shortText);
```

Esta es la imagen de como envía la información en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaré agradecido si me pueden ayudar con esta situación.

Comment: ¿Qué dice el error? Está mocha la imagen

Answer (score 0):

Solo faltaba indicar la libreria de Jquery

```js
var lengthText = 90;
//Aqui en la variable text guardas el texto antes de ocultarlo
var text = $("#trunc").text();
var shortText = $.trim(text).substring(0, lengthText).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";
console.log(text);
console.log(shortText);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.4.4/dist/vue.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.4.4/dist/vue.min.js"></script>



<div class="col-lg-10 ">
  <span id="trunc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: estoy utilzando lo junto con vue.js y ruby on rails por lo que la libreria js ya esta incluida,

Comment: alparecer vue hace un render por lo que envia la solicitud vacia cuando javascript pasa, y no se la razon por lo que lo envia, cuando el javascript pasa directo si funciona pero cuando lo trato de usar con vue.js manda vacio

Comment: Lalibreria jquery esta de primero despues el resto de todos los js son cargados despues

Comment: mmmm el resto de las librerias que estoy utilizando son moment y bootstrap del resto son cargadas con yarn

Comment: Edite el ejemplo con todas esas librerias y sigue funcionando

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema puede estar en la inclusión de jquery en tu documento.
Al usar tu código en [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2sfnmtjq/1/), este funciona sin problema.

Comment: ¿Qué recomendaciones pondrías para que funcione bien jquery o revisarlo?

Comment: Habría que ver mas código, de forma de entender que otras piezas podrían estar interviniendo. En rigor, podrían hacer un ejemplo en jsfiddle.

Comment: Ahora, podrían cambiar el orden de la carga de los js, dejar jquery al final.

Comment: También se me ocurre que puede ser que no sea el unico div que tiene ese id, y está tomando el último que tomo valor en el dom, y está vacío.